# Initial value for dropdown menu

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd like to set an initial value on my dropdown form of "Select an Industry". Once the user selects a valid value from the dropdown AND saves the form, ideally, this option wouldn't be visible anymore within the list if the user were to go back to the form. If there is no way to do this, that's fine.

Models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):                                     
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                                        
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)             
    industry = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Forms.py

```
class EditUserProfileForm (forms.ModelForm):       

    industry = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditUserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['industry'].choices = [(t.industry, t.industryname) for t in Industry.objects.all()]

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'phone', 
            'industry', 
           )
```

Is it possible to set a default value without creating an instance of the Industry object whose industryname is "Select and Industry"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `industry` is an integer representing entries in a separate table, then it is a foreign key. Make it an actual ForeignKey field; then Django will automatically output a select box for that related model in your form.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Good to hear from you again! Yes, I suppose that industry should be a foriegn key. I'm just wondering if the default text on the dropdown has to be an object of Industry of if it can be some random string like "test123". Thanks!